# Does PATCH supports Spring Data REST Projection?

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa, patch, projection

http://localhost:8555/api/users/1?projection=RiderLocationWithRider

In this API I used projection to get the data of Rider Location , it works fine but Now I want to use PATCH method to update user information and when I hit send it should return data along with projection data , but it only sends me rider data not projection data

Comment: Did you reach any solution for your question ?